# How to locate the element within CSS using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

The HTML elements' position are determined in a linked CSS.

```
div.title  
{  
position:absolute;  
top:12px;  
}
```

I can only use `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].position` to find the value of the position of the title, but how can I know this position belongs to the title?
In other word, how can the js code know the   `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]` is for the title?

Comment: Are you really looking for what's in the stylesheet? Or do you want the div's actual position value?

Comment: I just want to get the string "div.title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few browser differences when getting styles. To get a style rule generically:

```
function getStyleRule(s) {
  var sheet, sheets = document.styleSheets;
  var ruleProp, rule, rules;

  for (var i=0, iLen=sheets.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    ruleProp = ruleProp || (sheets[i].cssRules? 'cssRules' : 'rules');
    rules = sheets[i][ruleProp];

    for (var j=0, jLen=rules.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      rule = rules[j];
      if (s == rule.selectorText) {
        return rule;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you just want to match the first rule of the first sheet, then:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
alert( rules[0] );
```

and to see the selector:

```
alert( rules[0].selectorText );
```

and to see the styles that have been set:

```
alert( rules[0].cssText || rules[0].style.cssText);
```

Noting that some browsers will return exactly what is written in the style sheet and others will return their interpretation of that (i.e. it is implementation dependent and can't be directly compared across browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question:

You can use `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].selectorText` which will give you 'div.title'

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got an "undefined" is this method has some compatibility problem with different browser

Comment: You mistaked "selectorTect" for "selectorText" Thank you all the same.

Comment: It will fail in browsers that use *rules* instead of *cssRules* (such as versions of IE).

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the style is the one you want by iterating the stylesheets then the rules within (two loops)

definitely not very efficient compared to getting computed styles instead, but here's an example

```
// iterate stylesheets
var css = document.styleSheets;
for (var i in css) {
    if (!isNaN(i)) {
        // iterate rules in the stylesheets
        for (var j in css[i].cssRules) {
            if (!isNaN(j)) {
                var rule = css[i].cssRules[j];
                if (rule.selectorText.indexOf('div.title') > -1) {
                    // do something with position value
                    alert(css[i].cssRules[j].style.position);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/eAPdy/)